# how to disable all script and stylesheet in one page wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

how can I prevent wordpress from loading ALL calls for js files and css files. so that you only have the html file that generates wordpress?
More precisely I'm using a child theme. I can edit the `function.php` file. i used:
`wp_deregister_style( '(the handle) ' ); 
wp_dequeue_style("(the handle)"); 
wp_dequeue_script( '(the handle)' );
wp_deregister_script('(the handle)');`

 but for many handle didn't work and i search (if exist) a script that remove all calls in one.

Comment: Only on one particular page?

Comment: yes i need only for one page

Comment: What is the page ID?

Comment: the page id is: 25655

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your WordPress **child theme** functions.php file:

```
function childtheme_prefix_remove_scripts() {
    if ( is_page(25655) ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'handle' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'handle' );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_prefix_remove_scripts', 999);
```